# Spin Hamiltonian for 2 electron system

Tags: two-level-system, exchange-interaction

[image]I am currently studying exchange interaction and came across the spin operator in Ashcroft and Mermin Chapter 32 page 680 which states that the spin hamiltonian can be defined as:

```
                       [spin hamiltonian][1]][1]
```

I am able to understand the first part of the Hamiltonian which basically writes down the eigen energies associated with the singlet and triplet states and their respective probabilities. Can someone explain to me the part which consists of difference in energy of singlet and triplet state times the scalar product of spin operator of both the states.

Comment: The formula does not display in your post.

Comment: Oops, i thought I had attached the picture but it turn out stack exchnage didn't add the picture to the post

Comment: The formula is still misplaced. Please use mathjax by the way.

Comment: It is an instructive exercise to diagonalize this hamiltonian.